# How to make name be a variable in python?

Tags: python

How should I do if I want to output "name[0] = 6" instead of "t"?

[image]

Comment: please read content submission rules. You should be using formatting tools to provide us your code instead of pasting a screenshot of the code.

Comment: Please do not post code as images

Comment: The result of `print name` is `table2`.

Comment: Please post code as just that code, not as an image. See [mcve].

Comment: This has nothing to do with "variable variables". This man just want to print the name of the variable.

Comment: @FlorinGhita I am fairly certain the OP wants `name` to reference `table2`. IOW, they want to dynamically execute a string as Python code, and that is the canonical duplicate, despite its unfortunate title. The answer is the same, though, which is that you can use `eval` to do this, but you almost certainly shouldn't. If you disagree, feel free to vote to re-open, or perhaps the OP can clarify.

Comment: Yes, he want a dynamic code and you're right, generating code is a bad ideea.

Answer (score 0):

`print "name[0] = "+name[0]` for python 2 #concatenation

`print ("name[0] = "+name[0])` for python 3

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
print("name[0] = 6") # will work on python2 and python3
```

or

```
print "name[0] = 6" # only in python2
```

This will make python think that it is just a string, not a variable.